# Different rows for results while using the SQL case statement for same value

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate, case-statement

The result should be in a single row with logged in and not logged in counts. Why it is coming in two different rows for same account?

```
SELECT distinct  Account
     , SUM(CASE Val WHEN status='logged in' THEN  1 Else 0  END) AS 'Total logged in' 
     , SUM(CASE Val WHEN status='not logged in' THEN  1 Else 0 END) AS 'total not logged in '
FROM TableAccount 
GROUP BY Account

account    logged in    not logged in
A            21             0
A            0              2
```

Comment: Need some sample data

Comment: Why do to have a `DISTINCT` and a `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Check your data. Maybe you have values of `A` with spaces before or after. To make sure try: `SELECT ltrim(rtrim(Account))...GROUP BY ltrim(rtrim(Account))`

Comment: Could you please provide the table structure and data?

Comment: This is just a sample query of my actual problem. Since I can't post my actual query here.

Comment: The first A isn't the same as the second A, as forpas suggested, you might have hidden characters in one of them so they are actually different values. It's that or you are grouping by another column and not displaying it.

Comment: Even if its a sample, it needs to be a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be giving the result as desired if your table structure is same.

```
create table test1(col1 varchar(10), col2 varchar(10))

insert into test1
values('A','L'),
('A','NL'),
('A','L'),
('A','L')

SELECT distinct  col1
     , SUM(CASE WHEN col2='L' THEN  1 Else 0  END) AS 'Total logged in' 
     , SUM(CASE WHEN col2='NL' THEN  1 Else 0 END) AS 'total not logged in '
FROM test1 
GROUP BY col1
```

Comment: This query is giving me the desired result. But, the actual query has some conditions I think that's why it's not working for that.

Comment: I think I have to apply some different approach to the actual query. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT DISTINCT`is almost never needed with `GROUP BY`.  Also, you are correct, there should only be one row for `'A'` -- assuming the account is exactly the same.

The fact that you are getting two rows means that they are not the same.  One issue could be trailing blanks.  You can check for this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT '|' +  Account + '|'
FROM TableAccount ;
```

Other problems could be characters that look the same or hidden characters.  Finding the problem might require some investigation.